# curlftpfs rw permission denied

Tags: shell, ftp, gcc, curlftpfs

i connect my macosx with server ftp with curlftpfs, because i must change one file in every subdir (500), and i do with shell script, but  file give permission denied . this my script
curlftpfs ftp://ftp.redincontri.com /users/oscarristolfi/ftp4 -o user="6979334@aruba.it:xxxxxxxx",allow_other,ftp_port=-,kernel_cache,allow_other,direct_io,umask=0002,uid=1501,gid=1020

the command curlftpfs doesn't accept option "fuse rw", i have installed last release, and xcode too. I don't arrive to understand why .
this the screen

iMac:Desktop oscarristolfi$ cp /Users/oscarristolfi/index.html /Users/oscarristolfi/ftp4/www.redincontri.com/milano/cerco-amici/bella-persona-per-bei-momenti/ cp: /Users/oscarristolfi/ftp3/www.redincontri.com/milano/cerco-amici/bella-persona-per-bei-momenti/index.html: Permission denied
iMac:Desktop oscarristolfi$